# Getting a specific Settings in Sub and manipulating it

Tags: vb.net

I want a sub which gets a already existing variable from `My.Settings` and save it with `NewValue` variable. The example below shows what I need, but the problem is `My.Settings.a` is not from a `Settings` property, but a `String` one.

```
Private Sub Testing()
    ThisSettings(My.Settings.a, "123")
    ThisSettings(My.Settings.b, "456")
    ThisSettings(My.Settings.c, "789")
End Sub

Private Sub ThisSettings(Sett As Settings, NewValue As String)
    Sett = NewValue
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

Comment: Those are Properties, you're getting the Property value passed like that. You can probably use `NameOf()`, e.g.  `ThisSettings(NameOf(My.Settings.a), "123")`, then it may become `My.MySettings.Default.Item(Sett) = NewValue`

Comment: Note that `NewValue` should be declared `As Object`.

Comment: Never do this.  If the setting value causes the app to crash then it will crash forever, over and over again using the corrupt saved value.  With no decent way for the user to fix the problem, the setting file is quite hard to find.  Even re-installing the app won't fix it.  There is no hurry, settings get saved automatically when the program ends normally.